# Error conexión proxy

Tags: git, github, proxy, github-desktop

cree una conexión a proxy en una carpeta local que nunca funciono,  por error borre dicha carpeta y cree otra, pero al tratar de conectarme con github para hacer pull a los archivos me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Failed to connect to 0.0.173.67 port 1080 after 0 ms: Network unreachable.
```

Compruebo la configuración de mi entorno y en efecto me aparece la conexión al proxy en la carpeta que borre y al ingresar el comando git config --global --unset http.proxy, no se desconecta de el. También probe descargar a través de github desktop pero me dice lo siguiente:

```
Could not resolve proxy:xxxxx
```

Alguien me puede colaborar?, soy nuevo usando git.

A petición de eftshift0 pongo las salida de los siguientes comandos.

```
git config -l --global
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/kiadom/PrimerProyecto.git
remote.origin.proxy=192.168.116.191
remote.origin.proxy=44355
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=D:\Universidad de Antioquia\Ciclo 3\scrum semana 
1\RepositorioQuimbayaDev

git config -l
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain    
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f     
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f   
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
pull.rebase=false
:
```

Comment: podrias colocar la salida de estos comandos en la pregunta (como texto, plis, no con screenshots)? `git config -l; git config -l --global`. Por lo menos, las partes que sean relevantes. Y bienvenid@ a SO!

Comment: Listo, deje lo que me solicitas que creo es relevante, la carpeta que borre es scrum semana 1, de ahí en adelante o existe nada pero en git permanece la configuración como se evidencia. muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y la bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

Veo 2 cosas bastante raras.

Primero, en la configuración **global** hay un remote? Eso no debería estar ahí. Los remotes se configuran en cada repositorio.

Segundo, hay dos lineas de proxy para dicho remote. Elimina el segundo proxy (que de paso, ni si quiera es una dirección IP. `173 * 256 + 67 = 44355`, de ahí viene esa dirección IP que está poniendo en el mensaje de error. Ahora me pregunto: `44355` es el puerto del proxy? Entonces la dirección del proxy debería ser `192.168.116.191:44355`).

En general, si un proxy lo usas para *todo* y no solo para un remote, podrías configurarlo en el global:

```
git config --global -w http.proxy 192.168.116.191:8080
```

(asumiendo que el puerto del proxy es 8080, usa el que corresponda).

Comment: Bueno te cuento que 192.168.116.191:44355 es la ip y el puerto proxy que me da la app http injector para conectarme a internet, es lo que uso para poder acceder a la red desde mi laptop, por eso asumí que era lo que debía usar en la configuración, como elimino el segundo proxy y lo del remote ya que --unset no me funciona.

Comment: Siendo tu, yo abriría el archivo de configuración global en un editor de texto _decente_ (o sea, que reconozca y respete el formato de salto de línea de los archivos), y quitaría lo relativo a lo del proxy. Y se guarda y listo. Luego procedería a ponerlo con git de la forma que te dije en la respuesta.

Comment: Ese archivo lo encuentro en la ruta donde se instala el git?, lo busco pero no aparece Global

Comment: En linux, el archivo es `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: Hombre muchas gracias por la colaboración, he logrado conectarme de nuevo sin proxy por ahora. Lo intentare luego cuando deba pero el comando                                   ~/.gitconfig me funciono en w10 y lo edite con notepad++, luego fue solo clonar el repo solucionar un: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories y listo.

Comment: Excelente. Y cuando dije `~/.config`, no es para que lo ejecutaras. Esa es la ruta al archivo para que lo abrieras con un editor de texto.... como efectivamente hiciste.... bueno, creo. :-D

Comment: jejeje bueno si lo ejecute y abrió el archivo, el caso es que funciono.... gracias